# creating an Element and assign it to a variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, concatenation, createelement

Hi hope someone can help me out:
I am creating and element in JS like this:

```
let ptag = document.createElement("p");
    // create textNode
    let pNode = document.createTextNode("X-Done");
    // append pNode to paragraph
    ptag.appendChild(pNode);
    console.log(ptag);
```

Output is: `<p>X-Done</p>` which is what I am expecting.

But when I put the ptag in this line of code:

```
let para = document.createElement("p");
// create textNode
let myNode = document.createTextNode(i + ". " + invoer + ptag);
// append myNode to paragraph
para.appendChild(myNode);
let elem = document.getElementById('myDiv');
elem.appendChild(para);
```

the output is: 1. sss [object HTMLParagraphElement] when I add it in a div on the screen.

Why does it return [object HTMLParagraphElement] and not X-done in a paragraph?
Thank you already for clearifying and is this possible ?

Comment: because your `ptag` is a DOM element. Try using `ptag.innerHTML` instead

Comment: what is `i` and `invoer`?

Comment: Nice, thanks for you response. I am trying to make a todo list: 
i is a counter and invoer is the input from a input field that seems to work fine.

Your assistance is bringing me almost there, I am now getting the output:

1. Invoer X-Done in a p tag. How can I get the ptag in its own p-tag?
As I want to make the X-Done clickable, so that I can remove the the entire p tag.

Comment: Nice, thanks for you response. I am trying to make a todo list: 
i is a counter and invoer is the input from a input field that seems to work fine.

Your assistance is bringing me almost there, I am now getting the output:

1. Invoer X-Done in a p tag. How can I get the ptag in its own p-tag?
As I want to make the X-Done clickable, so that I can remove the the entire p tag.

Made the p a span, but still it is now a whole p tag.
Sorry I am a new to JS.
https://www.screencast.com/t/mt8O9wzVR1AG 
see this and you will understand. Thanks

Comment: Try removing `ptag` from `document.createTextNode(i + ". " + invoer);`. Then add your `ptag` to your `para` using `para.appendChild(ptag)` after `para.appendChild(myNode);`

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to do this: **". " + invoer + ptag**.

```
let ptag = document.createElement("p");
let pNode = document.createTextNode("X-Done");
ptag.appendChild(pNode);

let para = document.createElement("p");
let myNode = document.createTextNode("text");
para.appendChild(myNode);

let wrapper = document.createElement("div");
wrapper.append(ptag);
wrapper.append(para);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you put your `ptag` inside the `createTextNode`, turning it into a string. Try using the content of your `ptag` like:

```js
let ptag = document.createElement("span");
// create textNode
let pNode = document.createTextNode("X-Done");
// append pNode to paragraph
ptag.appendChild(pNode);


let i = "i";           // Added because they are no where to be found in your snippet
let invoer = "invoer"; // Added because they are no where to be found in your snippet

let para = document.createElement("p");
// create textNode
let myNode = document.createTextNode(i + ". " + invoer);
// append myNode to paragraph
para.appendChild(myNode);
para.appendChild(ptag);
let elem = document.getElementById('myDiv');
elem.appendChild(para)
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for you response. I am trying to make a todo list: 
i is a counter and invoer is the input from a input field that seems to work fine.

Your assistance is bringing me almost there, I am now getting the output:

1. Invoer X-Done in a p tag. How can I get the ptag in its own p-tag?
As I want to make the X-Done clickable, so that I can remove the the entire p tag.

Made the p a span, but still it is now a whole p tag.
Sorry I am a new to JS.
https://www.screencast.com/t/mt8O9wzVR1AG 
see this and you will understand. Thanks

Comment: @easyrlj Then instead of adding it inside the `createTextNode`, append it to the `para` just like you do with the `myNode`. See my updated snippet

Comment: This is working fine now, I have a other question in addition, is it possible to add a click function to this dynamic generated span?